# Unable to get feature names after One-Hot Encoding the categorical features

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, one-hot-encoding

I am trying pass my dataset (combination of numeric and categorical features) through a pipeline which does the necessary imputations, scaling and one-hot encoding (for categorical features).

In return the output would be a `pandas.DataFrame` with the new feature names (after encoding) as headers.
The code snippets are as follows:

```py
num_pipeline = Pipeline(
steps = [
    ("Imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median')),
    ("Scaler", StandardScaler(with_mean=False))
        ]
)

cat_pipeline = Pipeline(
steps = [
    ("Imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ("Encoder", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)),
    ("Scaler", StandardScaler(with_mean=False))
        ]
)



preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
  [
    ("Numerical_Pipeline", num_pipeline, num_columns),
    ("Categorical_Pipeline", cat_pipeline, cat_columns)
  ]
)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Ridge, Lasso, ElasticNet
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

X_train = preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train)

X_train = pd.DataFrame(data = X_train, columns = preprocessor.get_feature_names_out())
```

However, I am running into an error as this one.
[image: Attribute Error]

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to solve this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please copy and paste code snippets instead of linking a picture. This makes it easier for us to reproduce the problem on our machines and look for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, I do not have enough reputation to make a comment)
Besides ensuring you have an updated version of scikit-learn, I would do what the error message suggests, access the last step in your pipeline before calling the method. i.e. replace the last line in your snippet with
`X_train = pd.DataFrame(data = X_train, columns = preprocessor[:-1].get_feature_names_out())`

Comment: That was my first intent on solving it. However, that popped up another set of issues. So for the time being I using pandas.get_dummies() to get over the hurdle.